# For IOS push how to send an array message

Tags: php, api, rest, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

The message that is passed as a parameter is an array.But the push is not getting sent, whereas if I send a string the push is getting sent successfully to IOS.

```
public function sendIosPush($registatoin_ids, $message) {

    set_time_limit(0);

    $this->logger->write("INFO :","message for IOS PUSH".$message);

    header('content-type: text/html; charset: utf-8');
    $passphrase = '******'; 
    $deviceIds=$registatoin_ids;
    $body['aps'] = array('alert' => $message);
    //$payload = '{"aps":{"alert":"' . $message . '","sound":"default"}}';
    //$result = 'Start' . '<br />';

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

    foreach ($deviceIds as $item) {
        //sleep(1);
        $fp = stream_socket_client($this->iosServer, $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

        // Build the binary notification
        $payload = json_encode($body);

        $this->logger->write("INFO :","message for IOS PUSH".$payload);

        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $item) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

        // Send it to the server
        $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
        if ($fp) {
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }
    //set_time_limit(30);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use JSON for transfer message ....

after get message, you can decode JSON and parse it to array or any thing you want.

if you don't want JSON , also you can use xml ...

for convert to json in php you can use `json_encdoe` function.

**Update:**
this should be what you want :

```
public function sendIosPush($registatoin_ids, $message) {
    if(!is_array($message))
        $message=array($message);
    set_time_limit(0);

    $this->logger->write("INFO :","message for IOS PUSH".$message);

    header('content-type: text/html; charset: utf-8');
    $passphrase = '******'; 
    $deviceIds=$registatoin_ids;
    $body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => json_encode($message),
    'sound'=>"default");

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

    foreach ($deviceIds as $item) {

        $fp = stream_socket_client($this->iosServer, $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

        // Build the binary notification
        $payload = json_encode($body);

        $this->logger->write("INFO :","message for IOS PUSH".$payload);

        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $item) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

        // Send it to the server
        $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
        if ($fp) {
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }
    //set_time_limit(30);

}
```

Comment: I have done similar to what you have said.But its not working. Can you help me out with any working example

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendPushiOS($deviceToken, $pushMessage, $urlLink, $alertType)
{
    $iosServer='ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195';
    $deviceTokens = $deviceToken;
    $passphrase = '****';
    $urlis = $urlLink;
    $pushId = uniqid();

        $result = htmlspecialchars_decode($pushMessage) . "\r\n" . htmlspecialchars_decode($urlis);
    $message = $result;
    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

    $body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => $message,
        'sound' => 'busy.wav',
        'URL' => $urlis,
        'pushMsgId' => $pushId
    );

    foreach ($deviceTokens as $udid) 
    {

         $fp = stream_socket_client($iosServer, $err,$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
         $payload = json_encode($body);
          if (!$fp)
          {
            exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
          }
            $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $udid) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
            $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
            if ($fp) 
            {
                fclose($fp);
            }
            if (!$result) 
            {
                echo "<br/>" . 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
            } 
    }
}
```

Here $deviceTokens is array of device tokens.